# 14.10 VNC keyboard issue

Tags: unity, gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys, vnc

I've set up vnc4server on my ubuntu box (gnome session). (When monitor is connected to that box, I use Unity)

When I connected, I figured out that "s" and "d", and arrow keys are doing funny things, like they were pressed with  key (eg. app menu, minimize all, minimize, maximize).

I succeeded to eliminate "s" and "d" effects by disabling the relevant shortcuts in gnome dconf editor, but despite the fact I disabled all something shortcuts, up and down arrows are still minimizing and maximizing my windows.

How can I fix this annoying behavior?

Among other things tried:

- ccsm [Can't change keyboard shortcuts in gnome-session-fallback Ubuntu 13.04 over xdp](https://askubuntu.com/questions/297782/cant-change-keyboard-shortcuts-in-gnome-session-fallback-ubuntu-13-04-over-xdp?rq=1)
- system tools - preferences - keyboard - won't open app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, no solution until now.

- There was old bug in Gnome, it's unrelated and was patched in 2012
- Configuration tools even if I changed settings for other buttons through dconf up and down are still sending Super key
- Bug is unrelated to compiz
- Bug is reproduced on UltraVNC
- Only gnome session is affected, XFCE works flawless -> that's not completely true - on XFCE I can't `tab` to autocomplete in bash - it sends `alt+tab` insead.