# Custom shortcuts in Ubuntu 14.04 with gnome fallback session not working

Tags: 14.04, shortcut-keys, gnome-session-fallback

The custom keyboard shortcuts I set using the keyboard preferences windows is not working.

As per [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/297782/cant-change-keyboard-shortcuts-in-gnome-session-fallback-ubuntu-13-04-over-xdp) link I am able to assign custom shortcut for "show desktop" only. But my shortcuts for "File Manager" etc is not working.

How can I enable this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this using CompizConfig Settings manager.
Under "Commands" I added my command and configured the ketboard shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use configuration editor like dconf-editor (sudo apt-get install dconf-editor), it'll automatically create default setting or a copy from another desktop setting (e.g. Ubuntu Desktop) if you happen to login on it for the first time.

For manually edit window manager keybindings, it should be here: org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings, or just search for it.

You'll need to type the keyword/value manually tho', it is a low-level editor.

Comment: I could see options to edit short-cuts of existing actions. Not able to add new actions like "Open nautilus"